# WPF - Element is invisible but has dropshadow effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shadow, effects

I need an effect where I have my elements **invisible** but they actually **do drop shadows**. Is it possible to do that and if so, how?

**EDIT:** if this is impossible, I'm okay with using my elements (images and labels) as `masks` so only the shadow is visible. I'm going after some silhouette effects.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Here is the button itself:

```
    <Button x:Name="login_button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{DynamicResource TileTemplate}"
             Margin="5,10,5,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" 
                                  Color="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Color,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Opacity="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Opacity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0">
                </DropShadowEffect>
            </Grid.Effect>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/textures/logos/lock.png"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10" Visibility="Visible" OpacityMask="White">
            </Image>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                   Content="LOG IN" FontSize="40" FontFamily="CenturyGothicRegual"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <!--<Label.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Color,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     Opacity="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Opacity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Label.Foreground>-->
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD1A139" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF0A300" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

So the shadoweffect is applied **exactly under the elements themselves** and the plan is that only the harsh shadow is visible. I aimed to dodge image coloring (and importing various images) with this.

Comment: Certainly, just a sec

Comment: The effect is part of the control so the control's visibility / opacity effects the effect.  There's plenty of ways to do this but one might be to just add an empty borderless control behind the button and have the effect on that one.  Bind the size etc to the button so that it's the same width / height as the button... You get the idea.  Or you could even show hide the contents of the button (grid in this example) and not the button itself, and have the effect on the button.

Comment: Actually in this example you're applying a template to the button.  In the template is where you want the grid and on the button is where you want the effect.  Then just show / hide the template.

Comment: Good idea, though I got around by using `paths` and `shapes` available in Blend. I do have to apply the colour change template to all my button's grid elements, but I did what I wanted to. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back then I found a solution, Visual Studio Blend has a nice feature with paths and shapes. If you draw a path and merge it, it will be resolution independent and perfect for that silhouette effect I was after.

Comment: What was code solution that Blend created?