# Hide UIElement but display that element's Effect

Tags: wpf

I am drawing a sequence of lines with `DropShadowEffect` in WPF. I want all the effects to display behind all the lines. So I drew the sequence twice: The first time I set `Line.Stroke` to `Transparent` and added the effect, and the second time I set `Line.Stroke` how I wanted and left off the effect. Unfortunately, a transparent stroke seems somehow to hide the effect as well, so my first sequence of lines doesn't display anything. Setting `StrokeThickness` to 0 also hides the effect. How can I show `Line.Effect` without showing the `Line` itself?

As commented, [WPF - Element is invisible but has dropshadow effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471591/wpf-element-is-invisible-but-has-dropshadow-effect) asks the same question I do, but I want a code solution if possible, not just a Blend feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471591/wpf-element-is-invisible-but-has-dropshadow-effect this might help. The OP speaks of using blend to create the shadow as a seperate thing I think.

Comment: @EpicKip He's asking my precise question. I may have to mark my question as a duplicate. Unfortunately, his accepted answer isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: What is this supposed to look like, if it worked?

Comment: If the answer isn't what you want you don't have to mark it as duplicate. You might want to edit your question and mention that one and explain why the solution does not work for you so people don't incorrectly mark this as a dupe. Because if you're looking for a different answer it actually means your question is different

Comment: Oh and could you share your code? Preferably a minimal verifiable example (the minimum code needed to demonstrate the issue so people can replicate)

Comment: I think you need code and a clear explanation of the required result.

Comment: But what happens where the lines were?
A drop shadow is literally the line blurred and offset. 
You could offset the line and blur it. Done.

Comment: @Andy `DropShadowEffect` offsets automatically, which seems much easier. I'll grab some code to post.

Comment: As an aside here, I tried asking ChatGPT. I know this is banned. It suggested setting Stroke to null, which doesn't compile, then suggested setting Visibility to Collapsed, which hides both line and drop shadow and shows nothing, and then suggested setting Opacity to 0, which does the same thing, then suggested setting StrokeThickness to 0 and Stroke to Transparent, which still doesn't show anything. It then suggested using a Path instead of a Line. That solution still didn't show anything. Five plausible solutions, none of which actually work, I can see why we're banning it.

Comment: They literally cannot work because the gaussian algorithm is calculating a gradient based on colour it's found. Transparent or nothing is invisible.

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure I have my answer without posting code. I needed to know how `DropShadowEffect` works; now I do. I need to go rethink my method of achieving my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dropshadoweffect is a sort of gaussian blur.

It takes pixels and sort of copies them offset.

You need something to copy.

So the answer is no, you cannot.

You could maybe try clipping the line to remove it, but I would think that's going to give you a hole where the line was.

In fact if you take the question as stated then the shadow is a blurred version of the line offset by a few pixels.

If your line is say:

```
    <Line X1="0" X2="100" Y1="0" Y2="150"
          StrokeThickness="5"
          Stroke="Black">
        <Line.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Line.Effect>
    </Line>
```

The shadow is something like:

```
    <Line X1="4" X2="104" Y1="3" Y2="153"
          StrokeThickness="5"
          Stroke="Black">
        <Line.Effect>
            <BlurEffect/>
        </Line.Effect>
    </Line>
```

If this is not exactly what you want I could give you code which does a box blur on a black white image.

It's not as neat as gaussian but gaussian is hard to code. You'd have to paint your lines then blur em.

For interest

This is an explanation of the gaussian algorithm:

[https://blog.en.uwa4d.com/2022/08/11/screen-post-processing-effects-chapter-1-basic-algorithm-of-gaussian-blur-and-its-implementation/#:~:text=Gaussian%20Blur%2C%20also%20known%20as,pixel%20values%20in%20the%20field](https://blog.en.uwa4d.com/2022/08/11/screen-post-processing-effects-chapter-1-basic-algorithm-of-gaussian-blur-and-its-implementation/#:%7E:text=Gaussian%20Blur%2C%20also%20known%20as,pixel%20values%20in%20the%20field).

Comment: I didn't know a dropshadow effect was just a blurred line, pretty cool!

Comment: I'm already manually setting the color of the effect differently from the element. Why doesn't this work if the original color is Transparent rather than, say, Red?

Comment: In games when you don't have none of this fancy wpf stuff.... You take the outline of the sprite, offset it and apply a coded blur. Then bit blit the background first. @EricKip

Comment: @Lyndon Gingerich because gaussian blur is sort of averaging the colour you have in the line with an offset pixel. If there's no colour in the line then not a lot to average. If you are interested you could read up on the gaussian blur algorithm. I use a mathematical implementation on a 2d grid of elevation values to even out elevation between contours in our map editor to give smoother slopes.